# Can't seem to ever understand margin: 0 auto;

Tags: positioning, centering, margins

To my understanding all you need for margin: 0 auto; to center the content is:

1. display: block;
2. No floats
3. No absolute positioning
4. And a set width

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

I can apply text-align: center, and this will center is, however I just want to center with the margins. Any ideas.

`Here is the pen:` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JovwoJ

Comment: Which browser and version?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox, latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

It is working, you just don't have another element wrapped around it to see that it is centered and its `width` is set to `100%` so you can't see that it is centered because it takes up the full width.

HTML & CSS:

```css
    .wrapper
    {
     width: 80%;
     margin: 0 auto;
     display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <div style="width:100%">
    <div class="wrapper">
    
        <div class="nav-bg">
          <div class="nav">
            <a href="">Solar Panel Kits</a>
            <a href="">Solar Water & Pool</a>
            <a href="">Portable Solar</a>
            <a href="">Solar Panels</a>
            <a href="">Solar System Parts</a>
            <a href="">Emergency Solar</a>
            <a href="">Sale</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="info1-bg">
          <div class="info">
            <div class="inner2">
              <b>Free Delivery Wordwide</b>
              <b>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignis</b>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="info2">
            <div class="inner2">
              <b>Free Return For 90 Days</b>
              <b>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignis</b>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="info3">
            <div class="inner2">
              <b>Discount On Order Gift</b>
              <b>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignis</b>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="slider">
            <img src="">
          </div>
          <div class="learnSolar">
            <div class="learn1">
              <b>Get Insight On</b>
              <b>Solar Basics</b>
            </div>
            <div class="learn1">
              <b>Get Insight On</b>
              <b>Solar Rebates</b>
            </div>
            <div class="learn1">
              <b>Schedule A Free</b>
              <b>Solar Analysis</b>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="footer-bg">
            <div class="footer">
              <a href="">Customer Service</a>
              <a href="">Contact Us</a>
              <a href="">Blog</a>
              <a href="">Links</a>
              <a href="">Learn More</a>
              <a href="">FAQ</a>
              <a href="">About Us</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

`text-align` is just centering the `display:inline` elements that are inside of your `wrapper` div.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrapper set to 100% width. With that, `Margin: 0 auto;` will automatically center the wrapper by giving it left and right margins of 0, since it's already taking up the entire page. You could set the wrapper to `width: 90%;`, or anything besides 100% to have it center correctly.

Further, the divs that are inside of your wrapper are all block elements, meaning they will take up the entire width of your wrapper. Which is why, even when it's centered correctly with Alex W's answer, it isn't centered by our standards.

*Edit: I posted this because the previous answer didn't mention the wrapper width problem before it was edited, and I'm not able to make comments yet.*